# TSQL - Max or Top Date on an unnormalized table

Tags: sql, t-sql, subquery

I have the following table:

Table: UserName

```
Userid   User        UserUpdate
1        Dan           1/1/2005 
1        Dan           1/1/2007 
1        Dan           1/1/2009 
2        Pam           1/1/2005 
2        Pam           1/1/2006 
2        Pam           1/1/2008 
3        Sam           1/1/2008 
3        Sam           1/1/2009
```

I need to extract the latest updated for all these users, basically here's what I'm looking for:

```
Userid   User        UserUpdate
1        Dan           1/1/2009 
2        Pam           1/1/2008 
3        Sam           1/1/2009
```

I've tried doing a SELECT TOP or Max but get only the latest result, i.e. 1 result for the WHOLE table, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT Userid, User, Max(UserUpdate) AS MaxDate
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Userid, User
```

Comment: This my warrant another question... but what if instead of field "user" I have "FirstName" and "LastName"? If I do a group by on those then I would get duplicate rows back with different FirstName and LastName, how might I just extract the one with the latest date?

Comment: `SELECT Userid, FirstName, LastName, Max(UserUpdate) AS MaxDate
FROM myTable GROUP BY Userid, FirstName, LastName`. If that doesn't work, please post sample input data & output data for people to understand why that won't work.

Comment: Fair Enough, I posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259386/tsql-select-max

Answer (score 0):

group by and max

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Userid, User, MAX(UserUpdate) from myTable GROUP BY Userid, User
```

Comment: User is not in the group by, so this won't work. You'd need either max(User) or group by userid, user